# Mocking call to static method call inside spy method

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Pretty new to mockito. Stuck with a basic thing:

```
@Override
    public void updateMeeting(Meeting meeting, Meeting oldMeeting, List<MeetingOccurrence> oldMeetingOccurrences, List<MeetingOccurrence> newMeetingOccurrences) {
        Predicate<Meeting> update = (e) -> MeetingUtil.needReminderChange(oldMeeting, meeting, oldMeetingOccurrences, newMeetingOccurrences);
        // DO STUFF
            if(ConfUtil.isRecurrenceMeeting(meeting.getType()) && meeting.getType() == oldMeeting.getType()){
                update = update.or((e) -> recurringMeetingDurationChange(oldMeetingOccurrences, newMeetingOccurrences));
            }
            
        }
        if (update.test(meeting)) {
            sendEvent(meeting, MeetingConstants.MTG_CHANGE_EVEN_TYPE_UPDATE, getNotifiers(meeting, oldMeeting));
        }
    }
```

//---
TEST CLASS

```
public void testUpdateMeeting(){
        MeetingNotifyService meetingNotifyService = Mockito.spy(MeetingNotifyServiceImpl.class);
        Meeting meeting = Mockito.spy(Meeting.class);
        Meeting oldMeeting = Mockito.spy(Meeting.class);
        meeting.setType(Constants.MTG_TYPE_RECURRENCE);
        meetingNotifyService.updateMeeting(meeting,oldMeeting,null,null);
    }
```

//--

Problem is that when the code hits this line: `ConfUtil.isRecurrenceMeeting` it fails. It happens because of static block code inside ConfUtil. How can I tell mockito to not actually call `ConfUtil.isRecurrenceMeeting` and just return `true`. I cannot use powermockito

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMockito to mock the static method. But the best way I would suggest you to avoid PowerMockito and have your code designed as testable code. So you don't have to mock a static method, consider to have it as a singleton service and you just have to mock a service normally.

Comment: thank you very much